# Reinstalled MikTeX and now latex.exe doesn't work on simple document

Tags: miktex, standalone, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I reinstalled just now (updating packages seemed broken) in order to help look at fixing another question I posted.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont
$X$
\end{document}
```

Here's the output at command line:

```
latex.exe latex_input.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

No log is produced.  I just had it working with an old version of MikTeX.  What's wrong with my document?

---

I opened up TeXWorks, pasted in the above code and ran with: `pdfLaTeX + makeIndex + BibTeX` in the combo box next to the play button.  That works.  The first two options: `pdfTeX/LaTeX` give the "stymied" errror.

So how do I select that option when running from the command line?

Comment: your format is is wrong. Normally miktex handles the recreation, but perhaps some old format is in the way, or the build process fails for some reason. Try to recreate it in the miktex console (user mode), settings, tab format.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see my edit at the bottom

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I got it to work now.  I guess when the user installs MikTeX we'll have to run a test to make sure my app can see it correctly.

Comment: Having similar problems myself, I discovered that the "Install just for you" (something like that) stores everything in different locations after which nothing worked right.  The "install for all users" option is working (so far) but wiped out all my sty files (AGAIN!).

Comment: There seems to have been an issue with a mix recent latex.exe my current ends 2.6-1.40.19 (yours 40.18) and the core engine version mine is 2.9.6880 (yours was/is 2.9.6350) several users are experiencing issues with updates across such a wide time interval and you may ned to run update several times. Also the error message suggested the formats in such a case may need to be refreshed/rebuilt and that may include a system reboot before MiKTeX system stabilises.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following problem:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
```

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

```
  C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

if anybody will help me I really thanks!

send me your help vi chanieasmamaw@yahoo.com

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We not sent answers via your e-mail. It (if any) will appear as answer below your question). Recent MiKTeX has pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7). Your is quite old.  How you reinstalled MiKTeX?

Comment: If you happen to be needing this for rendering LaTeX from a program you're writing, I've found that rendering a KaTeX or MathJax template inside of a QWebEngineView (for Qt applications I write) to be a better solution than calling MikTeX - they're much faster options when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Go to command line and type:

`where latex`

Be absolutely positive that the MikTeX you've just installed is listed first.  Clean up old installs if you don't need them and edit your Path env variable accordingly.

Comment: It is probably best to use **where /r \ latex.exe** on each possible drive that may contain tex files the /r will search recursively all folders starting from \ root